# Oauth error string contains escape characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I set Oauth error string which is serialized json .

```
context.SetError(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnmsg));
```

returnmsg is something like this

```
  var returnmsg=new ErrorMessage();
  returnmsg.PasswordExpired = true;
  returnmsg.Success = true;
```

however when i call the endpoint and see the response in fiddler, the error string has backslashes added.

```
 {"error":"{\"PasswordExpired\":false,\"Success\":false}"}
```

this response is unparseble json and i am looking for way to make sure that response does not have unnecessary backslashes.

Comment: *this response is unparseble json*, no, it is a JSON object with a string property called `error`.

Comment: What is `context` here?

Comment: @PatrickHofman context is OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext